# VB.NET: Lambda expression, use assignment operator instead of equality

Tags: vb.net

I have a method that takes an System.Action, this is what I'm trying to feed it:

```
Function() Me._existingImports = Me.GetImportedAds()
```

The thing is that it complains about the = sign since it thinks I'm trying to do a comparison, which I'm not. I want to assign the Me._existingImports the value of Me.GetImportedAds(), but VB.NET complains about DataTable not having a = operator.

How can I force it to use the assignment operator instead of the equality operator?

In C# this works perfectly fine:

```
() => this.existingImports = this.GetImportedAds()
```

For now the solution will be to use a standalone method, but that's way more code than needed.

Comment: You found a *really* good reason to upgrade to VS2010

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `Function()`, you really define an anonymous *function* which means you map values to values.

Therefore `Function()` strictly needs an expression (like `x` or `42` ...) as the body, which an assignment is *not*! (Assignments don't evaluate to values like in C-style languages in VB)

Thus what you need is not a `Function()` but a `Sub()`, which contains statements (actions) rather than values.

```
Sub() Me._existingImports = Me.GetImportedAds()
```

C# doesn't distinguish here, the (much nicer) `... => ...` syntax covers it all.

Comment: Well, I tried with Sub(), but that gives errors. This is using VS2008.

Comment: Yeah right. Anonymous `Sub()` have been added with VB2010 and unfortunately - up to that point - you don't really have a nice way of working around it.